# How to find the impactness between the features?

Tags: machine-learning

I need some guidance, source, and articles where to look in my search. I am kinda lost about where to look and what to look for. So basically I want to find the synergistic effect or interconnections effect of one source on the other source. For Eg: the attribution of TV is let's say 10% of overall sales, but TV includes some interconnectedness for other media-driven sales within like (x%) of Digital driven TV sales, or (y%) on Print driven TV sales, including (z%) of TV base driven TV sales. We need to find the values of x, y, and z by studying the interconnectedness between the media variables. How to find those x, y, and z? I am looking at integrated gradients and Shapley values by which we can find the attribution of the model.

But is there any way to find how much a feature impacted to another feature maybe during finding attribution?

Comment: Have you thought of Principal Components Analysis (PCA)?

Comment: @OliverMason How PCA will help me solve this? Can you explain little?

Comment: PCA is used to identify the most important factors in combinations, so it might help you to identify those factors which are most relevant.